# CommAddIns missing add-in after downgrading to Office 2019

Tags: python, excel, windows, automation, excel-addins

I used to have Python code that checks whether a specific Excel CommAddIn is installed every time before performing an automated task in a Windows VM:

```
excel = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

for addIn in excel.COMAddIns:
       if str(addIn) == "Name of Add-in":
           break
       raise RuntimeError("Add in not found in Excel")
```

This worked fine, however after downgrading from Office 365 to Office 2019 due to licensing reasons, this code no longer works - although the add-in is installed in Excel and works fine - the rest of the code executes as before, the add-in is just not in the **excel.COMAddIns** list.

Any ideas?

I was expecting this to work just as it worked in Office 365. Apparently there is a way to check whether the add in is installed through checking a registry key, although I didn't find one that is suitable.